# How to group strings with whitespace, using sed?

Tags: regex, shell, sed, sh, backreference

Suppose my text file with the following strings:

```
Apple foo foobar
Banana foo foobar1 abc b c
Orange barfoo
Pear foo
```

How do I group the strings that comes after `Apple`, `Banana`, `Orange`, and `Pear`?

I could do this for `Apple`, but this wouldn't work for the rest of the text files.

`sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)/\2 \3/'`

I want the output to look like this:

```
foo foobar
foo foobar1 abc b c
barfoo
foo
```

Is there a general case where I can print these strings after the first whitespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/^[^ ]+[ ]+//' in.txt
```

(GNU sed; on OSX, use `-E` instead of `-r`).

---

**Update**:

As @Jotne points out, the initial `^` is not strictly needed in this case - though it makes the intent clearer; similarly, you can drop the `[]` around the second space char.

The above only deals with *spaces* separating the columns (potentially multiple ones, thanks to the final `+` in the regex), whereas the OP more generally mentions *whitespace*.

**Generalized whitespace version**:

Note: In the forms below, `\s` and `[:space:]` match all kinds of whitespace, including newlines. If you wanted to restrict matching to spaces and tabs, use `[ \t]` or `[:blank:]`.

```
sed -r 's/^\S+\s+//' in.txt
```

(GNU sed; this form will *not* work on OSX, even with `-E`.)

**POSIX-compliant version** (e.g., for AIX - thanks, @NeronLeVelu):

```
sed  's/^[^[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]\{1,\}//' in.txt
```

Comment: In OPs example this can be shorten to: `sed -r 's/[^ ]+ //' in.txt`. Since `g`global is not specified, it will always take first column, until first space is found. And no need for brackets around one single characters, so `[ ]` is the same as one space without brackets.

Comment: on posix compliant use "[:blank:]" instead of " " and "\{1,\}" instead of "+" (on AIX by example)

Comment: @Jotne: Good points; I wanted to be explicit about matching from the start and the space char. - brackets def. not needed, though. The extra `+` at the end was to cover the case where _multiple_ spaces separate the columns (not a requirement of the OP).

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: Good point about using `\{1,\}` instead of `+` for POSIX compatibility, but `' '` (unquoted) or `[ ]` work just fine - no need for `[:blank:]`, unless `\t` chars should be matched, too - which, now that I think about it, is probably a good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Any reason it has to be sed?

```
$ cat <<EOF | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
Apple foo foobar
Banana foo foobar1 abc b c
Orange barfoo
Pear foo
EOF

foo foobar
foo foobar1 abc b c
barfoo
foo
```

Comment: +1. Probably the simplest in the case at hand. (One thing to note about `cut`: if there were _multiple_ space chars. between the fields, `cut` would treat them as separating empty fields.)

Answer (score 1):

GNU grep works too

```
grep -oP '(?<=\s).*'
```

Comment: +1. Or (as I've learned about an hour ago :)): `grep -oP '\s\K.*'`. (The latter has the advantage that it's easier to generalize to deal with multiple whitespace chars. - `grep -oP '\s+\K.*'` - which apparently won't work with look-behind assertions, because they must describe a fixed-length string.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about sed.

But you can just **remove the unwanted part** of each line using the multiline modifier:

```
/^\w+\s/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be solved by `awk`

```
awk '{$1="";sub(/^ /,x)}1' file
foo foobar
foo foobar1 abc b c
barfoo
foo
```

or with this:

```
awk '{sub(/[^ ]+ /,x)}1' file
```